# How fast can stimuli be administered for evoked potentials?

Tags: neuroscience, reference-request, electrophysiology, stimulation, evoked-potentials

I'm looking for a reference about the ability for sensory stimuli to generate separate evoked potentials in the brain.

**What is the maximum repetition rate for sensory evoked potentials?**

Comment: Separated by the brain? Or separated by your recording from the brain? In either case, it depends entirely on the stimulus you use. You need to find a paper that uses similar stimuli and see how many repetitions they use, not look for a general answer to "how many stimuli."

Comment: I'm voting to close as unclear what you are asking because your post is too unclear. The brain can separate many stimuli on one trial. If not, it would be really hard to have a conversation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For [auditory brain stem responses](https://emedicine.medscape.com/article/836277-overview) (ABRs) the click rate can be really high, as the auditory system is exceptionally fast, in the order of tens of stimuli per second (*e.g.*, [Rodriguez *et al* (2010](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/156055004X). This will still yield a good ABR. At around 40 ms, the transient ABR shifts toward a steady state response, in which peaks of the previous ABR start to overlap with the following [(Korczak *et al*., 2010)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/90a2/420ffb5a85e93a25a02ea6c073d3fd9ce82c.pdf).

The visual system, however, is a lot more sluggisch and needs more time to recover from prior stimulation. For example, [VEP](https://www.aao.org/bcscsnippetdetail.aspx?id=45cef5ac-2f4e-4b67-81ff-85f3fd02878c)s are generally recorded at a few stimuli per second. The transition from a transient response to a steady state response occurs at around 6 - 10 Hz [(Fishman *et al* (2001)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/10853056_Click-evoked_ABR_at_high_stimulus_repetition_rates_for_neonatal_hearing_screening).

<sub>**References**

**-** [Fishman *et al*., *Electrophysiologic Testing*, 2<sup>nd</sup> ed. FAAO](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/10853056_Click-evoked_ABR_at_high_stimulus_repetition_rates_for_neonatal_hearing_screening)

**-** [Korczak *et al*., *J Am Acad Audiol* (2012); **23**: 146–70](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/90a2/420ffb5a85e93a25a02ea6c073d3fd9ce82c.pdf)

**-** [Rodriguez *et al*., *Brazil J Otorhinol* (2010); **76**(1): 96-101](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/90a2/420ffb5a85e93a25a02ea6c073d3fd9ce82c.pdf)</sub>